# What type of encryption should i use

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption

I need to find out what type of encryption is suitable for me.
For my case i usually need to pass information from my mobile webapp to a .NET webservice via ajax.

To summarize:

(Encrypt using javascript)Mobile ---Encrypted Data--> WebService(decrypt in C#)

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with using SHA1. You could also use an encrypt with a salt using a specific key

Comment: @Atticus: SHA1 is a hash algorithm. You can't decrypt hashes.

Comment: You haven't stated what the *attack* is that you're trying to defend against but you're expecting to get advice on defending it. You need to tell us who is attacking you, why, what resources do they have, and what are they trying to get? It's impossible to describe how to defend against an attack when the attack is never specified.

Comment: basically i just want to prevent people from viewing my data(xml) which is in plaintext when it's being passed over the net via ajax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use **SSL** - than all your transmission will be secure and the changes in your code will be minimal (just putting `https` in front of your urls should be enough).

Comment: +1, he's already using a web app and AJAX, HTTPS is the way to go.

Comment: I agree, except in the scenario where SSL is not enabled on the server or does not have a certificate.

Comment: I do not have a cert. and my webapp is gonna be used with phonegap to build into a native app

Comment: Like Jakub Konecki@  use HTTPS
but please remember you must always submit from HTTPS page, Like 
Facebook got caught-out by that one.

Comment: You can generate a self-signed certificate quite easily, or purchase a cheap commercial one signed by a certificate authority such as GoDaddy, etc.  Definitely sticking with standard HTTPS is the right choice here. It works for banks, it'll work for you.

Comment: https uses RSA certificates, this can be cracked just using your public key ...

Answer (score 0):

Using https is not that enough because it uses mostly RSA encryption, which is crackable using prime number generator algorithm.

I suggest to use concatenated encryption process, use openssl RSA 4096 to encrypt aes key and use aes to encrypt your message. Beaware this is crackable also by eavedropping your communication and extracting your aes key.

I would suggest the following:
encrypt your aes key with any private algorithm you can write .. then encrypt the output with RSA .. on the receive end, decrypt RSA to get the encrypted aes key, use your algorithm to decrypt it, then use aes key to decrypt the data.

i suggest to keep on changing the aes key based on a some random value ..